# Can't bind to 'options' since it isn't a known property of 'full-calendar'

Tags: fullcalendar, angular12, angular-calendar

****Error Message:****

> Error: src/app/pages/calander/calander.component.html:1:16 - error
> NG8002: Can't bind to 'options' since it isn't a known property of
> 'full-calendar'.
>
> 1. If 'full-calendar' is an Angular component and it has 'options' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
> 2. If 'full-calendar' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component
>    to suppress this message.
> 3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.
>
> <full-calendar [options]="calendarOptions">
> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
> src/app/pages/calander/calander.component.ts:5:18
> 5     templateUrl: './calander.component.html',
> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> Error occurs in the template of component CalanderComponent.

I exactly followed the angular documentation here: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/angular

Imported Everything in app.module.ts

```js
import { FullCalendarModule } from '@fullcalendar/angular'; // must go before plugins
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid'; // a plugin!
import interactionPlugin from '@fullcalendar/interaction'; // a plugin!
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        MainComponent,
        LoginComponent,
        HeaderComponent,
        FooterComponent,
        MenuSidebarComponent,
        BlankComponent,
        ProfileComponent,
        RegisterComponent,
        DashboardComponent,
        MessagesDropdownMenuComponent,
        NotificationsDropdownMenuComponent,
        AppButtonComponent,
        UserDropdownMenuComponent,
        ForgotPasswordComponent,
        RecoverPasswordComponent,
        LanguageDropdownComponent,
        PrivacyPolicyComponent,
        HomeComponent,
        ProjectComponent,
        PlanetComponent,
        // FullCalendarModule
    
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        FullCalendarModule,
        ToastrModule.forRoot({
            timeOut: 3000,
            positionClass: 'toast-bottom-right',
            preventDuplicates: true
        }),
        NgbModule
    ],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Used it in my component file

```js
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import { CalendarOptions } from '@fullcalendar/angular'
@Component({
    selector: 'app-calander',
    templateUrl: './calander.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./calander.component.scss']
})
export class CalanderComponent {
    calendarOptions: CalendarOptions = {
        initialView: 'dayGridMonth'
    };    
}
```

Then passed this code in my HTML file and I got the above error.

```
<full-calendar [options]="calendarOptions"></full-calendar>
```

Comment: Can you specify which **version of @fullcalendar/angular was installed**?